# Increasing the font size is dramatically increasing the padding of header

Tags: html, css, fonts

I creating a page and was lost when I noticed that when I increase or decrease the font size of the header, the surrounding space increases in a drastic size. I don't have a padding for the h1 tag, but it looks like it is being added. I tried removing the padding for the nav, but it is only affecting the nav text itself, not the extra space that's bothering me.
Here is the code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Caviar, "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
  float: clear;
  text-align: center;
}
#main {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
/* start the whole heading section */

h1 {
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: "Alex Brush", "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
  padding-left: 2%;
  float: left;
}
nav h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
nav {
  float: right;
  font-family: Junction, "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  /*padding-top: 5.2%;
padding-right: 2%;*/
}
nav a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
nav a:visited {
  color: #000b26;
}
#header {
  background-color: #FF6978;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  box-shadow: 5px 6px 5px #000000;
}
/*end heading section*/

#container {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  margin-left: 0 auto;
  width: 96%;
  margin-top: 13%;
}
.small_head {
  font-family: Capsuula, "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  border: 3px solid #FFFF61;
  padding: .5% 5% .5% 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Check</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="font.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <!--open main div-->

    <div id="header">
      <h1>Checking Head</h1>
      <nav>
        <h2>
<a href = "index.htm">Navigator</a>
</h2>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!--close header-->

    <div id="container">
      <div class="small_head">Small Head</div>
    </div>
    <!--close container-->

  </div>
  <!--close main-->
</body>

</html>
```

Please help!

*Note: I have embedded fonts in another css, so please ignore the fonts.*

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `<h1`> tag naturally has a margin applied on it scaling with font-size. You want this in your css:

```
h1 { margin:0 }
```

Comment: One more question: I added that and now the black space is still there, but the text has gone up. Since I have it position fixed along with the container with a margin top in % (to make it flexible), when I resize the window, the container is going behind the header. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I think the best way to go about that would be to not have the margin top as a %. Just set margin-top to your header height, since header height is constant.

Comment: That works too! Thank you so much! But it wouldn't be flexible, that is my problem.

Comment: You don't want it to be flexible unless your header height is flexible! If the margin-top is less than the header height, you get the interaction that it goes under the header.

Comment: but my header is flexible. When I resize the window, the header element does resize, but the container goes behind when resized.

Comment: Ah I'm not sure about the details of your resizing. You'll have to do some math on that one!

Answer (score 1):

The h1 element has margin that is related to the font size via em. If you increase the font size, em is relative to the font size and, thus, margin is increased.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `max-height: <number of pixels> px` instead of `h1 { margin:0 }` and you will not affect the h1 margins.